# i need Insert spaces between a string in multi line text file matlab

Tags: string, matlab, file, text

I have this string in text file

```
 123456789
 987654321
 111111111
 222222222
```

How can I insert 1 space between each number in that text file?

for this out put :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: Open the file in an editor which has column editing mode (like Notepad++) and insert a column of spaces at all the places you want. Don't use a screwdriver to pound nails. It takes forever and wrecks the screwdriver.

Answer (score 1):

```
s=['123456789'
   '987654321'
   '111111111'
   '222222222'];    

s2=repmat(' ',size(s,1),2*size(s,2));
s2(:,1:2:end)=s
```

will give you

```
s2 =

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Update:

Use `dlmwrite` to save `s` to a space delimited text file like this:

```
 dlmwrite('testData.txt',s-'0',' ');
```

The character matrix `s` is converted to a numeric array in the range of 0-9 when with the subtraction of the `'0'` character.  See gnovice's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45991880/2254698) for reading, processing, and loading within the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can read, process, and output the data to the same file:

```
fid = fopen('your_file.txt', 'r+');   % Open for both reading and writing
data = fscanf(fid, '%c', Inf);        % Scan all contents into a character vector
data = regexprep(data, '\S', '$0 ');  % Insert space after all non-whitespace
fseek(fid, 0, -1);                    % Move file pointer to beginning of file
fprintf(fid, '%c', data);             % Output data
fclose(fid);                          % Close file
```